# Magento 2 setup:upgrade Change Dark Blue Color

Tags: magento2, cli

Silly questions, but a feasible one.

Where can you change the system color for setup:upgrade from the CLI or anything really using that awful dark blue.

You can never read it unless there is an error. Be a lot nicer to see what's populating especially when you add new modules without being 3 inches from the screen just to verify it's there.

Answer (score 1):

The command line colours are more likely in the settings of the terminal that you are using so for instance, on iTerm on the Mac, you can go to Preferences -> Profiles -> Colors to change the theme.

Answer (score 0):

Changing Terminal Colors In Ubuntu Linux, Please click below Link.

https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/changing-terminal-colors-in-ubuntu-linux/

To change the background color of your Ubuntu terminal, open it and click Edit > Profile.

Select Default and click Edit.

In the next displayed window, go to Colors tab.

Uncheck Use colors from system theme and select your desired background color and text color. You can also place an image in the background of your terminal by going to Background tab. To apply an image as terminal background, select Background Image option, and select the image file.

Once done with settings, click Close.

The selected colors will be applied to your terminal instantly.

Answer (score 0):

This was asked a while ago but the answers so far are only giving a workaround... You can turn off ANSI in the terminal but that's not what the OP was asking.

The bin/magento command has a switch to shut off ANSI output for the current action: *--no-ansi*

```
php bin/magento --no-ansi setup:upgrade
```